# List given folder everywhere it exists

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal

How to get a listing of all occurences of the folder `foo` (or `node_modules` in my case) in my home folder, like this:

```
~/a/foo
~/b/d/foo
~/b/d/e/foo
...
```

My goal is to *manually* remove all unnecessary `node_modules` folder from my hard disk which has very limited space.

Comment: **from my hard disk**  : Isn't it a bit brave to remove folders of a given name **everywhere**, even including that part, where the system-relevant files are stored?

Comment: Sure it is :-) That’s why I just need the list, and from there I’ll decide which ones can be removed.

Comment: Just pointing out: With your approach, you don't search the whole disk. You search only below your home directory. If this is really what you want to do, please update the text of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use **find** command:

```
find ~ -type d -name node_modules
```

To exclude nested `node_modules` directories, use `-prune` on the folders that are found to stop `find` from descending into them:

```
find ~ -type d -name node_modules -prune
```

And then, to delete:

```
find ~ -type d -name node_modules -prune -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Comment: How to limit to the first occurrence found in a line when you get something line `~/beta/node_modules/clean-css/node_modules` ?

Comment: for macos users, adding a path is necessary: `find . / -type d -name 'node_modules'`.

Comment: I think the nesting requires `-depth` to make sure the more deeply nested directory is considered first

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu : Maybe it is worth to point out, that, since you are considering everything below `/`, the command would likely have to be run as _root_. Of course it is very questionable that to blindly remove even matching entries below, say, /usr/bin, /usr/lib etc., but I admit that this is what the OP asked for.

Comment: Agree... Gonna change to home as find path

Comment: @DevonDahon, `find . -type d -name node_modules -print -prune`, I think

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu : IMO `-prune` does not help here. It just prohibits for a path of, say, `/opt/node_modules/x/node_modules/y` that the "lower node_modules" will be detected too. It does not keep find from stepping into directories it has no permission. Actually, find can not step into these directories anyway, but it would output an error message. However the OP **does** want to examine the whole hard disk, not skipping part of it. Hence, I don't see an alternative to run it with _root_ rights.

Comment: @user1934428, the OP wants to examine their *home folder* (they've now clarified that), hence the `~` in the answer, not the whole filesystem, nor *the whole hard disk* whatever that means.

Comment: Yes, he updated his question now. Especiall the first comment he gave (as answer to my comment) looked like originally, he wants to search everywhere below `/`. This request is not so unusual, if someone is using a computer just for himself (and also administering it), but since he is now happy with looking only in his own files, permission is not a problem anymore. Still, even after update, his question contains the sentence _remove all unnecessary `node_modules` folder from my **hard disk**_, and it's also in the title. I wished people would be more precise in their questions!